# Clarification needed for closed sets

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $F = \{f_{n} | n \in\Bbb N \}$ be an infinite collection of functions $f_{n}(x)=e^{−n(x−n)^2} , x ∈ \Bbb R$. Prove that $F$ is closed in $BC(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$ but not closed in $C([−a, a], \Bbb R)$ for any $a > 0$

Here $BC$ represents bounded continuous functions and $C$ represents continuous functions. The metric is given by the metric defined by sup norm.

My idea:

I found out the limit of $f_{n}$ and it is equal to $0$, i.e, $f_{n}(x)$ converges to $0$. But $0$ is not a member of $F$, so $F$ is not closed in $C([−a, a], \Bbb R)$ but I cannot seem to understand why the same is not true in the metric space $BC(\Bbb R, \Bbb R)$.

Please suggest a proof for the same and an explanation.

Comment: $f_n(n) = 1$ so $f_n$ can't converge to 0 in $BC$

Comment: @Tryss: But as $n$ goes to $\infty$, won't it converge to $0$?

Comment: It converge pointwise to 0, but not in BC. $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, ||f_n-0||_{\infty} = 1$

Comment: @Tryss: Do you mean to say that it doesn't converge uniformly in $BC$ because it is not clear from your comment.

Comment: Yes. In BC, the topology is the topology of the uniform convergence, not the topology of the pointwise convergence

Comment: So, is it that in $BC$ it has a limit given by $f(x)=1$ for $x=n $ and $f(x)=0$ for all other $x$. So how do you say that this $f(x)$ is in $F$ for $BC$? I am confused. Can you please post an elaborate answer

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing you need to understand is : what kind of convergence are we talking about?

Here, you have space of continous bounded functions, so it's the uniform convergence that's important.

It means $f_n \to f$ if and only if $\|f_n-f \|_{\infty} \to 0$

So now about your answers : for the space $C([-a,a])$ you say that $f_n \to 0$, and it's indeed true, because $0 \in C([-a,a])$  and for n large enough, $\| f_n \|_{\infty} \leq e^{-n}$. It implies that $F$ is not closed

For the space $BC$, as $f_n$ converge pointwise to 0, 0 is the only possible limit for $f_n$. But we have $\forall n, \| f_n \|_{\infty} = 1$. It means that $f_n \not\to 0$, so we can't say that $F$ is not closed.
And because $f_n$ has 0 as a pointwise limit, every subsequence of $(f_n)$ has 0 as a pointwise limit. You can use the same argument as before. It means that if $f_n \to f \in BC$, $f=f_k$ for a fixed $k$ (the sequence is stationnary), hence the set is closed